# Creating library project and integrating into existing project in android

Tags: android, fragment, android-library, slidingdrawer, library-project

I have an application that has got two basic screens, a home page and a sliding drawer menu fragment to the left of home page like the facebook sliding drawer. Now I am planning to create another page to the right of the home page that appears by sliding to the other side. i would like to create this as a library project and just import it to the existing project. how can I do this. I need to display the the new menu drawer on sliding after adding the library project. How can I achieve this ? That is, I will be having a fragment in the library project that populates data by all necessary api calls from server, and I need to inflate the fragment by sliding in the main project.

Comment: are you working in an Eclipse environment?

Comment: yes I am working on eclipse

Comment: I know how to add to built path and all, But I want a tutorial that helps me out in incorporating a module to existing project that is developed as a library project

Answer (score 0):

Saying all this in a paragraph is very simple.

First of all android does not provide Left and Right drawers. There is a custom project on github containing both left and right navigation drawers.

Now, you need to put some effort first, putting some code, some tutorials which you followed, and do you have a library project containing the right drawer ?

Comment: I do have a left drawer. Similarly I can built right. But current left drawer is built inside the core application. i want the new drawer as a seprate project, since its a independent module. I just want to know how can I use that library project in the main application, so that on sliding the home screen I need to show the drawer that i built on the library project

Comment: You need to read android documentations. In a single activity there can only be one drawer. Library projects are reference in project.properties. You created a left drawer in your core app and a right drawer in a library project. You can't merge them and make a left right drawer

Answer (score 0):

I find that vogella's site has some pretty good tutorials. For instance, [this tutorial on Android library projects](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html).

I hope this is what you're looking for  ;)